# Remove the extra " " in "lng " in array object javascript

Tags: javascript

The below code is for csv to array. I am getting an extra "space" in the output.
Example: 
output : {lat: 42.546245, "lng ": 1.601554} 
expected : {lat: 42.546245, "lng": 1.601554}
Help needed in removing the extra space in the "lng "header.

```
function initMap() {
mapLoad();
readFiles();

 }
function readFiles() {
const myForm = document.getElementById("myForm");
const csvFile = document.getElementById("csvFile");

  function csvToArray(str, delimiter = ",") {

    // slice from start of text to the first \n index
    // use split to create an array from string by delimiter
    console.log(str);
    const headers = str.slice(0, str.indexOf("\n")).split(delimiter);

    // slice from \n index + 1 to the end of the text
    // use split to create an array of each csv value row
    // const rows = str.slice(str.indexOf("\n") + 1).split("\n");
    const rows = str.slice(str.indexOf("\n") + 1).split("\n");

    // Map the rows
    // split values from each row into an array
    // use headers.reduce to create an object
    // object properties derived from headers:values
    // the object passed as an element of the array
    const arr = rows.map(function (row) {
      const values = row.split(delimiter).map(Number);
      const el = headers.reduce(function (object, header, index) {
        object[header] = values[index];
        return object;
      }, {});
      return el;
    });

    // return the array
    return arr;
  }

  myForm.addEventListener("submit", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const input = csvFile.files[0];
    const reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function (e) {
      const text = e.target.result;
      const data = csvToArray(text);
      console.log(data);
      mapLoad_1(data);
    };
    
    reader.readAsText(input);
  });
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use trim function on header

```
object[header.trim()] = values[index];
```

Comment: That did the trick. Thanks

Comment: @mute, consider marking the answer as accepted if it resolves your issue.

Answer (score -1):

When you get the title, you can remove all spaces through the trim() function

```
const headers = str.slice(0,str.indexOf("\n")).trim().split(delimiter);

const rows = str.slice(str.indexOf("\n") + 1).trim().split("\n");
```